# What effects do resources have?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Looking through the online manual, I can't seem to find any data on the actual effects of resources (ex. wine, timber, etc).  These resources are listed with special slots on the trade details widget.

I imagine the effects might be similar to Civ 5's resources, but it's really unclear exactly what they do, and what the bonuses might be for having them imported.

In general I'm just wondering how the effects of resources work?

Are resources necessary for certain military, cultural, or trade buildings?

Do they give public order bonuses?

Comment: I recall in Shogun 2 that access to certain resources (either by owning the province or through trade) was necessary to construct certain buildings. I don't have Rome 2  yet, but you might want to check the building tree to see if there's something similar going on.

Comment: That sounds correct from what I remember of previous games, but the interface seems to make special note of the fact that one has a resource available for import.   What's the benefit of importing the resource if it's only for building modification?   Unless it then lets you build the building wherever the trade route goes, but that seems weird.

Answer (score 2):

Having them makes trade more valuable, particularly with people who have different resources than you. This is similar to the civ 5 BNW system. From what I have noticed that's all they do now.

Answer (score 1):

Wine allows you to build the level 5 Circus Maximus as Rome in 1 city only so choose wisely :)

On one of the help boxes it said researching all of the technologies can allow the building of "wonders" but I cannot see what these are having fully researched one of the trees.

Comment: Yeah, all of the level 5 buildings require a resource I believe.